# Qchart Remove the line point from bottom

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts, qchart, qchartview

I am new in QT, I want to build a chart. In the chart, i want to show only line. You can see the picture with is attached. How can i remove this point?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78vCT.png) Thank you.

Comment: Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted.

Comment: that blue square is `chart legend` and it is active by default you can hide it. that wasn't point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should hide legends.

```
    chart->legend()->hide();
```

For example :

```
    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->setTitle("Simple areachart example");
    chart->createDefaultAxes();
    chart->axes(Qt::Horizontal).first()->setRange(0, 20);
    chart->axes(Qt::Vertical).first()->setRange(0, 10);

    chart->legend()->hide();

    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
```

**you can see what happens from this picture:**

```
    before                                                after
```

[image]

I use [this Qt Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-areachart-example.html)